# CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing despite header begin there

Tags: python, flask-restful

I'm making an api in flask-restful, and I'm trying to make a request, but when I try I get the error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/events/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
```

My code is:

```
class Event(Resource):
    def get(self, id=0):
        if id == 0:
            return random.choice(events), 200
        for event in events:
            if(event["id"] == id):
                return event, 200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
        return "Event not found", 404
```

I have added the header, but I stil get the error. Does anyone know what the problem is?
Also, if anyone needs it, the full code is here:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse
import random
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

events = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "starter": "a",
        "dungeon": "test a",
        "info": "A test event for the web app and api"
    },
    
    {
        "id": 1,
        "starter": "b",
        "dungeon": "test b",
        "info": "A test event for the web app and api 2"
    }
]

class Event(Resource):
    def get(self, id=0):
        if id == 0:
            return random.choice(events), 200
        for event in events:
            if(event["id"] == id):
                return event, 200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'file:///C:/Python/website%20test/index.html'}
        return "Event not found", 404

api.add_resource(Event, "/events", "/events/", "/events/<int:id>")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit:
Here is how I am making the request:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/events/");
request.send();
request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status == 200) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
    } else {
        console.log('API offline');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

install flask-CORS package.

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

and apply the following changes. On your current code.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
  return "Hello, cross-origin-world!"
```

Comment: What should i put in 'code logic'? can I just keep the code I have now, and instead of the api object use the cors object? I tried that but it just gave me an error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Just add flask_cors and cors variable to your code, and run it again. the issue is that you are getting blocked by your flask server because you are doing this in your localhost... try and tell me plz.

Comment: When I try, I get the error `AttributeError: 'CORS' object has no attribute 'after_request'`

Comment: please check answer, I've updated it. go back to your previous code and try this..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I made a type when adding the CORS library. adding the `cors = CORS(app)` fixed the issue.

Comment: did the previous answer worked for you ? or the updated one ?

Comment: It was the previous one.